# Ignoring newlines in textile document (under Eclipse wikitext)

Tags: markup, textile, mylyn-wikitext

As we have some old text-based doc for a project (for programmers), and would like to display it in a nice way, I installed Mylyn wikitext for that purpose. I plan to convert the doc to textile (or any other markup, that supports tables and has an easy-to-installable eclipse plugin). However, newlines are preserved in textile. Is there a way to tell textile (specifically to mylyn wikitext) not to break line on every lineend? Or at least is there a line continuation character?

The purpose of this is not to have a text file with huge line length, if you want to see it with a plain old text editor without any wrap adjustment (Eclipse cannot not wrap lines btw)

Answer (score 1):

In redmine it works by the (ugly) syntax

```
 this line won't&lt;notextile&gt;
 &lt;/textile&gt; be broken
```

Browsing the Internet I found other escape characters (==, \\), but no one applies to redmine textile I'm using.